# What kind of Gauss quadrature is this?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I found a formula for Gauss quadrature on the following link: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/lab/people/sd/lectures/nummeth98/integration.htm

What kind of Gauss quadrature is that in *Section 5.7, eq. 56*? It uses the constant $\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$. I can't match these weights with any Gauss quadrature variants found on the web.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's the usual Legendre polynomial of order 2.  But remember, that is usually on the interval $[-1,1]$, whereas the link you give is over $[0,1]$.  So instead of $\pm \frac1{\sqrt 3}$, it is $\frac12 (1\pm \frac1{\sqrt 3})$.

Comment: I see. But how 1/sqrt(3) become sqrt(3)/6?

Comment: $\frac12 \times \frac1{\sqrt 3} = \frac{\sqrt 3} 6$.

Comment: Sure thing. I should think twice before ask, haha. If you write your comment as an answer, I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the usual Legendre polynomial of order 2. But remember, that is usually on the interval $[−1,1]$, whereas the link you give is over $[0,1]$.  So instead of $\pm \frac1{\sqrt 3}$ it is $\frac12(1\pm\frac1{\sqrt 3})$.